# How to proces a JSON file with Multiple JSON root elements in Android

Tags: android, json

I'm making an app that retrieves a JSON file from a server to locate a marker on a map. My problem is that the JSON file that I'm retrieving from the server has multiple root elements.

This is an example of what the JSON file looks like.

```
{"class":"VERSION","release":"3.11","rev":"3.11-3","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":9}
{"class":"DEVICES","devices":[{"class":"DEVICE","path":"/dev/ttyUSB0","driver":"NMEA0183","activated":"2017-03-25T20:20:20.649Z","flags":1,"native":0,"bps":9600,"parity":"N","stopbits":1,"cycle":1.00}]}
{"class":"WATCH","enable":true,"json":true,"nmea":false,"raw":0,"scaled":false,"timing":false,"split24":false,"pps":false}
{"class":"TPV","tag":"RMC","device":"/dev/ttyUSB0","mode":3,"time":"2017-03-25T20:20:21.000Z","ept":0.005,"lat":18.487301667,"lon":-69.942863333,"alt":73.300,"epx":3.788,"epy":3.496,"epv":6.612,"track":352.7300,"speed":0.010,"climb":-0.100,"eps":7.58,"epc":13.22}
```

Since I don't handle the server nor what pases the JSON file with the info to the server. **Is there any way to process this file as it is? and how?** I know it's not in a valid JSON format. **Is there a way to only read the TPV class in the app on android?and how?** & **Is it possible to do any of this still on the AsyncTask?**

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [ to beginning of the string and a ] to end and treat it as JsonArray.

Comment: I tried that in https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ where i was evaluating what ways i could modify it. Still missing commas between the elements.

Comment: And them too. Look for the "class" string and add the comma before the {. Just jump the first one.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that would help me to make a method that does that job? (I'm pretty new to android) and thanks for the help!

Comment: @IvanOgando you can use the lastIndexOf method from the Java String to get the index of the "class", then add the ",". Another option is to ask here for a regex that will do it ;)